# Kafka Consumer by partition

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Hi appart consumer groups, is it possible to tell a consumer to only read a specific partition?

From what I have read and seen so far it doesn't seem like it or did I miss something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manually assign partitions to subscribe to using assign()

https://kafka.apache.org/0100/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#assign(java.util.Collection)

Comment: There are pros and cons to using manual partition assignment versus dynamic partition assignment but I would not say that either one is universally a good or a bad thing.